# How to inflate layout in EditMode?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a simple custom View which just extends LinearLayout and use simple XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And Java-code:

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            // How to inflate R.layout.my_custom_view here?
        } else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, this, true);
        }
    }

}
```

I want that my custom view will showing in Eclipse layout editor as a default layout (R.layout.my_custom_view). But it cannot inflate and show exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F03000B.
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getLayout(BridgeResources.java:271)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
    at ru.bartwell.myapp.MyCustomView.init(MyCustomView.java:29)
    at ru.bartwell.myapp.MyCustomView.<init>(MyCustomView.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

Is there way to inflate default layout in EditMode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

```
if(isInEditMode())
```

**To**

```
if(!isInEditMode())
```

Comment: When I do it I get exception Resources$NotFoundException like described.

Comment: comment the 1st constructor and try.

Comment: this should work, just clean your project and try again

Comment: You are right, I'm restart Eclipse and now it working fine. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If i call `inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, this, true)` I get a `NullPointerException` at `at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeXmlBlockParser.getLineNumber(BridgeXmlBlockParser.java:197)`